# How to download Files in folders and subfolders from different versions of Sharepoint (2007 and 2010) using CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, csom

I need to download the files present in various SharePoint folders from SharePoint 2007 and 2010 sites present in different domains.

I am trying to write Console application using CSOM in visual Studio 2015. I am currently able to download the files from one of the domains which is in SharePoint 2007.

I am facing the below errors when I am trying to fetch the files from other domains and SharePoint 2010.

1. when trying to connect different domain in SP 2010: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden
2. Cannot contact site at the specified URL `http://sp.abc.com/projects/A101site`
3. The remote server returned an error: `(500) internal server error`

My Current code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        string ProjectURL = "http://sp.abc.com/projects/A101site";
        ClientContext site = new ClientContext(ProjectURL);                    
        site.RequestTimeout = 600000;
        Web web = site.Web;
        site.Load(web);
        site.ExecuteQuery();
        site.Load(web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents"));
        site.ExecuteQuery();
        List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
        site.Load(list);
        site.ExecuteQuery();
        site.Load(list.RootFolder);
        site.ExecuteQuery();
        site.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);
        site.ExecuteQuery();
        int i = 0;
        var relUrl = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;
        Folder f = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(relUrl);
        FolderCollection fc = f.Folders;
        site.Load(f);
        site.ExecuteQuery();
        site.Load(fc);
        site.ExecuteQuery();
           foreach (Folder w in fc)
                    {
                        if (w.Name.Contains("SubFolder"))// && j == 0)
                        {
                            //j++;
                            site.Load(w);
                            site.ExecuteQuery();
                            site.Load(w.Folders);
                            site.ExecuteQuery();
                            foreach (Folder wsf in w.Folders)
                            {
                                site.Load(wsf);
                                site.ExecuteQuery();
                                if (wsf.Name.Contains("Actual Folder"))
                                {
         GetSubFolders(wsf.ServerRelativeUrl, i, ProjectCode, ProjectURL);
                                }
                                else continue;
                            }
                         }
                        else
                            continue;
                    }
}
public static void GetSubFolders(string folderUrl, int i, string ProjectCode, string ProjectURL)
        {
            ClientContext abssite = new ClientContext(ProjectURL);                       
            var absweb = abssite.Web;
            abssite.Load(absweb);
            abssite.ExecuteQuery();
            Folder f = absweb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);
            FolderCollection fc = f.Folders;
            abssite.Load(f);
            abssite.ExecuteQuery();
            processFolderClientobj(f.ServerRelativeUrl, i++, ProjectCode, ProjectURL);
            abssite.Load(fc);
            abssite.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (Folder w in fc)
            {
                abssite.Load(w.Folders);
                abssite.ExecuteQuery();
                processFolderClientobj(w.ServerRelativeUrl, i++, ProjectCode, ProjectURL);
                if (w.Folders.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach(Folder wf in w.Folders)
                    {
                        abssite.Load(wf);
                        abssite.ExecuteQuery();
                        string rel1Url = wf.ServerRelativeUrl;
                    GetSubFolders(rel1Url, i, ProjectCode, ProjectURL);
                    }
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }
        }
public static void processFolderClientobj(string folderUrl, int i, string ProjectCode, string ProjectURL)
        {
            string Destination = @"Folder Location";
            ClientContext site = new ClientContext(ProjectURL);
            var web = site.Web;
            site.Load(web);
            site.ExecuteQuery();
            Folder folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);
            site.Load(folder);
            site.ExecuteQuery();
            site.Load(folder.Files);
            site.ExecuteQuery();

            string newName = ProjectCode;
            foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file in folder.Files)
            {
               string destinationfolder = Destination + "/" + folder.ServerRelativeUrl;
                if (file.Name.Contains(".mpp"))
                {
                    i++;
                    newName = newName + "-" + i.ToString() + ".mpp";
                    Stream fs = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(site, file.ServerRelativeUrl).Stream;
                    byte[] binary = ReadFully(fs);
                    if (!Directory.Exists(destinationfolder))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationfolder);
                    }
                    //int index = file.Name.IndexOf(".");
                    string oldName = file.Name;
                    FileStream filestream = new FileStream(destinationfolder + "/" + file.Name.Replace(oldName, newName), FileMode.Create);
                    int index = newName.IndexOf("-");
                    newName = newName.Substring(0, index);
                    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(filestream);
                    writer.Write(binary);
                    writer.Close();
                }
                else continue;
                site.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
        public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your current code to can help you faster

Comment: Added the code as requested. Please check and let me know what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my solution using the msdn article below:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh124553%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

My issue was with the SP2010 using forms and windows authentication. hence I had to specify the hostheader as per the article explicitly for my code to work.

Regards
Agasthya